# How to get required image sizes from Adwords Api

Tags: google-ads-api

I am new to adwords api and can't find a way to get information such as "required image sizes" for example. That would return all the image sizes that google accepts. As in "Square 200 x 200, Vertical 120 x 600" etc.

Is there any way to get this information so I won't have to update my project if anything new added or removed from google side?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information about supported image sizes in the [Adwords documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722096).

For non-animated image ads, the following sizes are available:

- 200×200 **Small square**
- 240×400 **Vertical rectangle**
- 250×250 **Square**
- 250×360 **Triple widescreen**
- 300×250 **Inline rectangle**
- 336×280 **Large rectangle**
- 580×400 **Netboard**
- 120×600 **Skyscraper**
- 160×600 **Wide skyscraper**
- 300×600 **Half-page ad**
- 300×1050    **Portrait**
- 468×60  **Banner**
- 728×90  **Leaderboard**
- 930×180 **Top banner**
- 970×90  **Large leaderboard**
- 970×250 **Billboard**
- 980×120 **Panorama**
- 300×50  **Mobile banner**
- 320×50  **Mobile banner**
- 320×100 **Large mobile banner**